# Как поменять права на файл или директорию в Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Как поменять права на файл или директорию в Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить команду в терминале

```
chmod права [флаги] /путь/до/директории/или/файла
```

Для рекурсивного применения используем флаг -R.

Answer (score 0):

Как Выше было сказано - chmod- ом
Если для группы пользователей, то chown

Comment: Что значит для группы пользователей? chown меняет владельца файла.

Comment: chmod - меняет атрибуты файла
chown - владельца
chgrp - группу

Comment: Я группу менял chown'ом вместе с владельцем. Синтаксис примерно такой: chown [-R] user:group <путь-к-каталогу-или-файлу>